# How are unvoiced vowels represented in IPA？

Tags: phonetics

As far as I know, there are some unvoiced vowels in Japanese. For example, when 「す」 is at the end od a sentence, it will sound like [s]. Such process is referred to as 「無声化」. I wonder how to represent these unvoiced vowels in IPA？

Answer (score 1):

IPA has the devoicing diacritic ◌̥ (ring below) — you can see this used in the narrow transcriptions on Wiktionary for Japanese words that have devoicing such as [好き](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D).

Comment: Thanka a lot for your answer！It's helpful. And I have another question. Is such diacritic also used in broad transcription?

Comment: @Francis Komizu
It is not used in phonemic transcription of Japanese. But there are languages, which have contrasting voiceless and voiced consonants (not just one being allophone of another), e.g. [/m̥/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_bilabial_nasal) versus [/m/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_bilabial_nasal) (e.g. Burmese, White Hmong, Jalapa Mazatec, Kildin Sámi, Xumi).